# where query in daterange in rails with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date-range

How to use where queries with daterange in postgresql with Rails 4.2:

```
  ConsultingLocation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "consulting_locations".* FROM "consulting_locations" WHERE "consulting_locations"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "consulting_locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 495]]
  ConsultingLocationDoctorSchedule Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "consulting_location_doctor_schedules".* FROM "consulting_location_doctor_schedules" INNER JOIN "consulting_location_doctors" ON "consulting_location_doctor_schedules"."consulting_location_doctor_id" = "consulting_location_doctors"."id" WHERE "consulting_location_doctors"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "consulting_location_doctors"."consulting_location_id" = $1  [["consulting_location_id", 495]]
=> [#<ConsultingLocationDoctorSchedule:0x007fe7653f7538
  id: 1,
  consulting_location_doctor_id: 495,
  schedule_date: Mon, 05 Jan 2015 00:00:00 IST +05:30,
  slot_details:
   [{"end"=>"2015-01-05T03:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T02:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 2:30 am to  3:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T03:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T03:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:00 am to  3:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T04:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T03:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:30 am to  4:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T04:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T04:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:00 am to  4:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T05:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T04:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:30 am to  5:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T05:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T05:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:00 am to  5:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T06:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T05:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:30 am to  6:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T06:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T06:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:00 am to  6:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T07:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T06:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:30 am to  7:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T07:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T07:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 7:00 am to  7:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T08:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T07:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 7:30 am to  8:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T08:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T08:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 8:00 am to  8:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T09:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T08:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 8:30 am to  9:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T09:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T09:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 9:00 am to  9:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T10:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T09:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 9:30 am to 10:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T10:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T10:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"10:00 am to 10:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T11:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T10:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"10:30 am to 11:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T11:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T11:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"11:00 am to 11:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T12:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T11:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"11:30 am to 12:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T12:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T12:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"12:00 pm to 12:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T13:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T12:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"12:30 pm to  1:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T13:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T13:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 1:00 pm to  1:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T14:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T13:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 1:30 pm to  2:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T14:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T14:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 2:00 pm to  2:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T15:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T14:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 2:30 pm to  3:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T15:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T15:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:00 pm to  3:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T16:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T15:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:30 pm to  4:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T16:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T16:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:00 pm to  4:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T17:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T16:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:30 pm to  5:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T17:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T17:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:00 pm to  5:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T18:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T17:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:30 pm to  6:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T18:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T18:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:00 pm to  6:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T19:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T18:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:30 pm to  7:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-05T19:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-05T19:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 7:00 pm to  7:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""}],
  start_and_end_time: Mon, 05 Jan 2015...Tue, 06 Jan 2015,
  deleted_at: nil,
  deleted_by_id: nil,
  created_at: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 16:21:59 IST +05:30,
  updated_at: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 16:21:59 IST +05:30>,
 #<ConsultingLocationDoctorSchedule:0x007fe7653f7380
  id: 2,
  consulting_location_doctor_id: 495,
  schedule_date: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 00:00:00 IST +05:30,
  slot_details:
   [{"end"=>"2015-01-06T09:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T09:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 9:00 am to  9:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T10:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T09:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 9:30 am to 10:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T10:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T10:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"10:00 am to 10:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T11:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T10:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"10:30 am to 11:00 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T11:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T11:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"11:00 am to 11:30 am", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T12:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T11:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"11:30 am to 12:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T12:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T12:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"12:00 pm to 12:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T13:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T12:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>"12:30 pm to  1:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T13:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T13:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 1:00 pm to  1:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T14:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T13:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 1:30 pm to  2:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T14:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T14:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 2:00 pm to  2:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T15:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T14:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 2:30 pm to  3:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T15:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T15:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:00 pm to  3:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T16:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T15:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 3:30 pm to  4:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T16:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T16:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:00 pm to  4:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T17:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T16:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 4:30 pm to  5:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T17:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T17:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:00 pm to  5:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T18:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T17:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 5:30 pm to  6:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T18:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T18:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:00 pm to  6:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T19:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T18:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 6:30 pm to  7:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T19:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T19:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 7:00 pm to  7:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T20:00:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T19:30:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 7:30 pm to  8:00 pm", "appointment_id"=>""},
    {"end"=>"2015-01-06T20:30:00.000+00:00", "start"=>"2015-01-06T20:00:00.000+00:00", "title"=>" 8:00 pm to  8:30 pm", "appointment_id"=>""}],
  start_and_end_time: Tue, 06 Jan 2015...Wed, 07 Jan 2015,
  deleted_at: nil,
  deleted_by_id: nil,
  created_at: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 16:21:59 IST +05:30,
  updated_at: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 16:21:59 IST +05:30>,
```

Usually with simple date we would do Table.where(start_and_end_time: Date.yesterday..Date.today)

I tried :

```
where("start_and_end_time :@> ?",Date.yesterday..Date.today)
```

threw this error:

```
ConsultingLocation.find(495).schedules.where("start_and_end_time :@> ?",Date.yesterday..Date.today)
  ConsultingLocation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "consulting_locations".* FROM "consulting_locations" WHERE "consulting_locations"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "consulting_locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 495]]
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: ...sulting_location_id" = $1 AND (start_and_end_time :@> '2014-...
```

and it did not work. How to work with dateranges in general

---

This also did not work:

```
ConsultingLocation.find(495).schedules.where(start_and_end_time: Date.yesterday..Date.today)
  ConsultingLocation Load (103.0ms)  SELECT  "consulting_locations".* FROM "consulting_locations" WHERE "consulting_locations"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "consulting_locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 495]]
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed range literal: "2015-01-01"
LINE 1: ...on_doctor_schedules"."start_and_end_time" BETWEEN '2015-01-0...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis or bracket.
```

Comment: You have already answered your question by showing how it works, why are you trying a different way that does not work?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work, the way to automatically query dates in ActiveRecord is with `Table.where(start_and_end_time: Date.yesterday..Date.today)`. Not sure why you're trying something that clearly doesn't work here.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares This does not work, I have tried that! I am not trying something that clearly doesn't work, because the docs point to something similar to what I have posted. I updated the question, since someone else might assume the same.

Comment: Where at the rails docs have you found any reference that this that you're trying to do works?

Comment: Here is the link to docs regarding this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#range-types

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if a range contains another range:

```
where("start_and_end_time && daterange(?, ?, '[]')", Date.yesterday, Date.today)
```

If you want to know if a date falls within a range:

```
where("start_and_end_time @> ?::date", Date.yesterday)
```

I found these articles helpful:

1. https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/7/73/Range-types-pgopen-2012.pdf
2. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/RangeTypes
3. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#range-types
4. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html